# 500 Internal Server Error when making an AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sugarcrm

The problem:

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error when making an AJAX request, and am getting back this in the Chrome Console and I don't understand what I am doing wrong, I'm new to writing AJAX calls and handling them in PHP:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>\n<p>The server encountered an internal error or\nmisconfiguration and was unable to complete\nyour request.</p>\n<p>Please contact the server administrator at \n webmaster@mywebdomain.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,\n and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>\n<p>More information about this error may be available\nin the server error log.</p>\n<p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error\nerror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at mywebdomain.com Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Here is the javascript (I would add that I find it odd that it seems to want 'http' when everything on our server is 'https', If I change to 'https', then it brings back 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present'... nonsense, which isn' true, I specify that in the header, not sure if that's because this is the same domain):

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://mywebdomain.com/admin/custom/modules/cac_customize_agent_comp/views/getID.php',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text',
      data: {wnID: $("#wn_writing946b_number_ida").val(), pcgID: $("#aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1aos_products_ida").val()}
    })
    .done(function(response) {
       console.log("response");
       $("#displayText").html(response);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
       console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
       $("#displayText").html("There was a problem retrieving the records...");
    })
    .always(function() {
       console.log("complete");
});
```

And here is the php file:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');

$wnID = $_POST['wnID'];
$pcgID = $_POST['pcgID'];

function getDefaultPercentage($wnID, $pcgID){
        $sql = "SELECT wn_writing_number_cstm.title_c
            FROM wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c 
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing946b_number_ida = wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c
            WHERE wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c = '" . $wnID . "'";

            $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql);

            while($row = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result) ){
                $titleWN = $row['title_c'];
            } //end while


        $sql = "SELECT pcg_product_comp_grid_cstm.title_c, pcg_product_comp_grid_cstm.percentage_c
                FROM aos_products_pcg_product_comp_grid_1_c 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN pcg_product_comp_grid_cstm ON aos_products_pcg_product_comp_grid_1_c.aos_products_pcg_product_comp_grid_1pcg_product_comp_grid_idb = pcg_product_comp_grid_cstm.id_c
                WHERE aos_products_pcg_product_comp_grid_1_c.aos_products_pcg_product_comp_grid_1aos_products_ida = '" . $pcgID . "'";

            $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql);

            while($row = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result) ){
                $titlePCG = $row['title_c'];
                $percentage = $row['percentage_c'];
            } //end while

        if($titlePCG == $titleWN){

            $fullTitle = '';

            switch ($titlePCG) {
                case "TR":
                    $fullTitle = 'Trainee';
                    break;
                case "SA":
                    $fullTitle = 'Sub-Agent';
                    break;
                case "A":
                    $fullTitle = 'Agent';
                    break;
                case "GA":
                    $fullTitle = 'General Agent';
                    break;
                case "MGA":
                    $fullTitle = 'Managing General Agent';
                    break;
                case "FMO":
                    $fullTitle = 'Field Marketing Organization';
                    break;
                case "DM":
                    $fullTitle = 'District Manager';
                    break;
                case "RVP":
                    $fullTitle = 'Regional Vice President';
                    break;
                default:
                    "";
            } //end switch

        } //end if

        if($titlePCG != '' && $titleWN != ''){
            $textToOutput = $fullTitle . ": " . $percentage . "% is the default percentage.";
        }
        else {
            $textToOutput = "There was a problem retrieving the records...";
        }

        return $textToOutput;

    } //end getDefaultPercentage function

$textToOutput = getDefaultPercentage($wnID, $pcgID);

echo $textToOutput;


?>
```

Here is the php error I am getting from the error log:

```
[Tue Jun 14 14:25:37.752301 2016] [core:error] [pid 7823] [client XX.XX.XXX.XX:XXXXX] End of script output before headers: getID.php, referer: http://mywebdomain.com/admin/index.php
[Tue Jun 14 14:25:39.347480 2016] [:error] [pid 7822] [client XX.XX.XXX.XX:XXXXX] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/mywebdomain/public_html/admin/custom/modules/cac_customize_agent_comp/views/getID.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://mywebdomain.com/admin/index.php
[Tue Jun 14 14:25:39.347557 2016] [core:error] [pid 7822] [client XX.XX.XXX.XX:XXXXX] End of script output before headers: getID.php, referer: http://mywebdomain.com/admin/index.php
```

Comment: What do you see in the log of web server / php answering on `http://mywebdomain.com` ? That might give a solution hint.

Comment: Short of there being a *syntax* error, where is `$GLOBALS['db']` defined? I don't see any `include()`'d files in your PHP script.

Comment: @Dilettant, I have edited my post to include the php logs at the bottom.@Marcus, I'll double check to make sure that isn't the problem. You can read [here] (https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Helper_Classes/DBManagerFactory/) if you want to know more about that, but I went ahead and included the necessary files JUST in case.

Comment: Have you tried breaking the problem down in smaller pieces to identify which part of your code actually produces the error? Also please read this: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my problem was a permissions issue.

I moved the file back to the core directory, and decided to forget trying to get permissions just right on every folder in between, and bam, worked like a charm.

Case in Point, when you are getting a 500 error from navigating directly to the actual url, permissions is a likely suspect.

Also, the headers I included were not needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is some Syntax error in your code! That's why a 500 is shown.

Most probably you have to enable `display_startup_errors=1` in the `apache.conf` or `php.ini` or do a `ini_set();`

**P.S** Look for some more `blahblah_error=0` and change to `blahblash_error=1` and you're done.

And don't forget to restart the apache too after doing any of these changes